# Shuffling strings in Java

Tags: java, string, shuffle

While I am creating Java String shuffler, I am getting a problem:
program stucks somewhere.

1. I have to pass a sentence or a word through BufferedReader
2. I have to shuffle the word/sentence so that first element is the first letter, then last letter, then 2nd letter, then 2nd from the end till the job is done

   2.1. If word/sentence length is odd, the middle character has to be put in the end of the word/sentence.
3. Have to print it out
   Result should be like this:

   [image]

My code;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String enteredValue = null;
    int charArrayLength = 0;

    System.out.println("Dāvis Naglis IRDBD11 151RDB286");
    System.out.println("input string:");
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        enteredValue = br.readLine();

        charArrayLength = enteredValue.length(); // length of array entered
        char[] characters = new char[charArrayLength];
        characters = enteredValue.toCharArray();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    char[] tempChars = new char[charArrayLength];
    for (int i = 0; i <= charArrayLength - 1; i++) {
        tempChars[i] = enteredValue.charAt(i);
    }
}

/**
 * Shuffles the char array if it's length is even
 *
 * @param array
 */
public static void shuffle(char[] array) {
    char[] tempChars = null;
    for (int j = 0; j <= array.length; j++) {
        if ((array.length % 2 == 0) && (j < array.length)) { // array[j] == (array.length / 2) + 1
            tempChars[j] = array[array.length - j];
        } else if (array.length % 2 != 0) {
            tempChars[array.length] = array[j];
        } // end else if
    } // end for

    String shuffledSentence = new String(tempChars);
    System.out.println(shuffledSentence);
}
```

Don't look at multiple line comments, haven't changed them since start.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please include the code inside the question instead of providing a link to it.

Comment: Do you have to use a char array?

Comment: `shuffle` never gets called, and if you would call it, it would immediately crash with a nullpointer exception, since `tempChars` (within `shuffle`) is never initialized.

Comment: If your algo get stuck, run the code in your debugger and pause it, this will show you where it is getting stuck and if then step through the code you will see why.

Comment: @ammoQ Saw that..made many versions of code. This was my last attempt before taking advantage of StackOverFlow, seems that I have forgotten it... I'll make those changes and then I'll submit an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shuffling made easy:

```
int len = array.length;
char[] tempArray = new char[len];
int i=0, j=0, k=len-1;

while (i<len) {
   tempArray[i++] = array[j++];
   if (i<len) {
     tempArray[i++] = array[k--];
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, sir!
Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Wow. Your algorithm is too complex for this problem! 
Try this for shuffling:

```
int n = array.length;
char[] resChars = new char[n];
boolean flag = false;

if (n % 2 != 0) {
    flag = true;    
    char tmp = array[n / 2];
}

for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; j += 2) {
    resChars[j] = array[j / 2];
    resChars[j + 1] = array[n - 1 - (j / 2)]
} 

if (flag)
    resChars[n - 1] = tmp;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
String str;
char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
List<Character> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (char aChar : chars) {
    list.add(aChar);
}
Collections.shuffle(list);
String result = list.toString().replaceAll("[\\[\\],]", "");
```

Comment: I'll try all these variations of doing it a bit later! Thanks; will bring back the answer!

Comment: No, this doesn't get the pattern asked in the question. Just randomizes the array and strips out commas

Answer (score 0):

Your program doesn't stuck, it exits properply.

> Process finished with exit code 0

There is no more work to do for the process, since you don't call
your static shuffle method.

In addition, as the others already answered, your static shuffle method needs some design
refactoring.