# How to shuffle in Android Studio using JAVA

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm reading text document file and displaying it on screen word by word. On button click it displays next word by random but some times it will repeat some words. So I did some research and I figured that it's best for me to use `shuffle`. How can I manage that. Here's my code:

```
public void Random_Word(){
    String text = "";
    try {
        InputStream is = getAssets().open("challenges.txt");
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        text = new String(buffer);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    String[] separated = text.split("\n");
    int size = separated.length;
    int randomNum = (int) (Math.random() * size - 1);
    String randomWord = separated[randomNum];

    word.setText(randomWord);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shuffling strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35718169/shuffling-strings-in-java) However, those answers may not work with unicode character consisting of more than two bytes (e.g. some flags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your main problem is repeating words then I have an alternative solution for that

you can create an array of strings and every time you generate a new random word check if it is already in the list. if it exists then you can generate a new random word else you can display it.

let's see how:-
create an array in your java class or activity.

```
ArrayList<String> words_array = new ArrayList<>();
```

and in your void `Random_word();` you can add this code.

```
public void Random_Word(){
String text = "";
try {
    InputStream is = getAssets().open("challenges.txt");
    int size = is.available();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
    is.read(buffer);
    is.close();
    text = new String(buffer);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
String[] separated = text.split("\n");
int size = separated.length;
int randomNum = (int) (Math.random() * size - 1);
String randomWord = separated[randomNum];

if(words_array.contains(randomWord)){
//word already exists so call method again
 Random_word();
}else{
 //add word in array and display it
 words_array.add(randomWord);
 word.setText(randomWord);
}
}
```

I know this is not the answer to your question but this can solve your problem.